# How to split Spring MVC request mapping by parameter value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC 3 I want to handle the same url with two different controller classes - depending on value of url parameter. **@RequestMapping** annotation even has such field: **params**, and I thought following would be two different mappings (I use mapping on class level):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", params = "name=val1")
```

and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", params = "name=val2")
```

but it's not. Spring throws exception for second case that controller for **/myurl** already mapped (by first case).

Is there some accurate solution for splitting request mapping by parameter? May be extending @RequestMapping or using proxy as controller and call different controllers depending on parameter...
Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**
This works but only on methods level, not on class level...
This will:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl")
public class Class123 {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"edit.htm"}, params = "src=1")
    public String open1(Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception {....}

    @RequestMapping(value = {"edit.htm"}, params = "src=2")
    public String open2(Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception {....}
}
```

this won't:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", params = "src=1")
public class Class123_1 {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"edit.htm"})
    public String open(Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception {....}
}


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/myurl", params = "src=2")
public class Class123_2 {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"edit.htm"})
    public String open(Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception {....}
}
```

And I would like to split logic in different classes.

Comment: That should work. I've used it, it works. Something else is going on that you haven't shown us. Perhaps some other controller has mapped that URL.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this only works for methods in the same class. Not sure if that's a bug or not, though, although the documentation doesn't mention it. Perhaps you could keep the methods in one class, but then delegate to another class to keep the implementations separate?

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. May be problem is that I dont define default mapping, narrowing down from class to methods (smth like **/myurl/***) Following this direction about delegating I thought about making kind of proxy class that will call one of implementations for appropriate method. But this want simplify my task for sure

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a difference between using RequestMappingHandlerMapping (new in Spring 3.1) vs DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping (the class replaced by RequestMappingHandlerMapping).