# Spring, POST different models on the same URL

Tags: java, spring

How to process different models from POST request on the same URL?

For example, I have field `action` in the user model.

If `action` equals to `edit`, I know, that user sent me model for editing entity.

If `action` equals to `delete`, I know, that there are other fields and other model.

How to do this on the same URL and don't use any optional GET parameters?

Comment: this question asked something similar, and figured out how to do it inside 1 class. however it looks like it only works if you specify the whole param string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208210/how-to-split-spring-mvc-request-mapping-by-parameter-value

Answer (score 1):

Normally for REST based URL nomenclature the operation (PUT, DELETE, GET etc) is decided by the URI and not my the model. So if you follow the right conventions then DELETE and PUT operations should be different actions on your controller. But if you want to push the operation inside the model then you probably don't need multiple actions. Single action with a single request mapping can consume the user model and then in your service or helper you can do an `if else` check on the model's `action` attribute to see what to do about it.

Comment: Yeah, I know it, so my question is a quite theoretical. But in some other languages (like PHP), it's very easy to do this thing. I just want to know, how to do some flexible things like this.

Comment: Java is not PHP. PHP is a free form language. Just the path of the script is enough to call it. The approach I said above is the way to go if you want to defer the `action` decision in the model.