# Handle same URL in different controllers based on parameters - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller which handles a specific URL

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/myurl"})
public ModelAndView handleMyURL()
```

Instead I want to have 2 separate controllers that let me handle this same /myurl based on the parameters passed to it.

If URL is

```
/myurl?a=1
```

goto controller A, otherwise use controller B.
Is there a way to do that?

I found this similar question  [Spring MVC - Request mapping, two urls with two different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571307/spring-mvc-request-mapping-two-urls-with-two-different-parameters)
where someone has mentioned "use one method in a misc controller that dispatches to the different controllers (which are injected) depending on the request param." , how do I implement that?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208210/how-to-split-spring-mvc-request-mapping-by-parameter-value?rq=1) question has a similar approach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Controller 1

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/myurl"}, params = { "a" })
public ModelAndView handleMyURL()
```

Controller 2

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/myurl"}, params = { "b" })
public ModelAndView handleMyURL()
```

Take a look at chapter 4 of [this post](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping) for more detail

Answer (score -4):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value= {"/myurl"})
public TestController{
    @Autoware 
    private TestAController testAController;
    @Autoware 
    private TestBController testBController;

    public void myMethod(String a){
        if(a.equals("1"){
            testAController.foo(a);
        }else{
            testBController.foo(a);
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value= {"/myurl1"})
public class TestAController{
   public void foo(String a){
    ...
}
}
```

---

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value= {"/myurl2"})
public class TestBController{
    public void foo(String a){
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but I don't like this. If you don't want to use two separate controllers (it is possible, see other answer) and want one controller to "control" the behavior of the url, I suggest 1) split the business services and keep one controller, or 2) if really want 2 controllers managed by one controller (maybe you have a lot of parameters to handle, or whatever) just redirect to other controller; do not call directly a controller method.